# Intergrating Slack with Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, slack-api, orchardcms-1.9

I am attempting to use a web request to post updates to Slack whenever content is versioned via the Workflow module, but it keeps failing to post correctly, and send the error email I have programmed to send if the web request fails.

I am trying to post to a slack using a webhook url, and I have tried to send the body text as JSON using:

payload={"text": "A very important thing has occurred!  for details!"}

or just:

{"text": "A very important thing has occurred!  for details!"}

Both work when I test using a client like POSTMAN, but not within Orchard.

I can not see any logs to get/give more feedback on what's happening either.

Anyone have success?

Comment: How do you post it from orchard? Workflow, Driver, Custom REST-Client?

Comment: @Xceno I am trying to use a workflow.   Here's a screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx8uNWDV-PmReTF4aVB5SHNzMkk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the json in double parentheses so that the tokenizer does not try to process it. Something like this:

((
"text": "A very important thing has occurred! for details!"
))